# Display flagged email in task pane

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I've just upgraded from Outlook 2013. When I opened my To-Do List view, all flagged emails were displayed in a narrow list on the left hand side. The currently selected email were opened in a reading pane on the right hand side.

Now, after the upgrade to Outlook 2016, the previously narrow list view takes up the whole screen unnecessarily. I don't get to see any of my emails.

[image]

How can I regain my reading pane on this page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple suggestions:

1) Ensure the Reading Pane is enabled for the Tasks/To-Do view. Check *View* tab -> *Reading Pane* -> Ensure it's set to something other than "*Off*".

2) Try *View* tab -> *Reset View* while looking a the Tasks/To-Do list.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Your first suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

on windows 10 go to:
"View"
"To-Do Bar"
select "tasks"
you will now be able to see your flagged emails on the right of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Outlook Office 365, you can just click the Filter button up and to the right of your email list.  Then choose Flagged.  It shows all your Flagged emails. Other options to Filter are: Unread, To me, Flagged, Mentions, Attachments and Sort.

Answer (score -1):

Click View- Click Arrange BY. go down to view settings. click sort by. change the first to flag status, and the second sort to by received decending. Flagged emails will now be at the top

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).